# traffic coming from onelink.to URLs not shown in Google Analytics 4.0

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

i have a mobile application on both android and ios & i created an sms campaign for it sharing a link to download the app through onelink.to (which makes one link to download either android or ios app).

I got the analytics of the app through google analytics 4.0 , but cannot see the traffic coming from clicking the generated link from onelink.to

when i open the link from mobile it redirects me to google play / app store depend on the type of mobile and then open the app from there. but still source or medium showed in GA

note :
app links in onelink.to built using Google campaign URL builder ; passing the utm_medium & utm_source parameters.

what is the problem ?